# Why do I need both mod and use to bring a module to the scope?

Tags: rust

Why do I need to write `mod` and `use` when I want to bring a module to the scope?

```rust
mod from_other_file;
use from_other_file::sub_module;

fn main() {
    sub_module::do_something();
}
```

If I do this it gives me error because the module isn't imported inside the current file:

```rust
use from_other_file::sub_module;

fn main() {
    sub_module::do_something();
}
```

Error Message:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `from_other_file`
 --> src/main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use from_other_file::sub_module;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `from_other_file`
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`use` and `mod` are doing two very different things.

`mod` **declares** a module. It has two forms:

```rust
mod foo {
    // Everything inside here is inside the module foo
}

// Look for a file 'bar.rs' in the current directory or
// if that does not exist, a file bar/mod.rs. The module
// bar contains the items defined in that file.
mod bar;
```

`use`, on the other hand, brings items into the current scope. It does not play a part in defining which files should be considered part of which module namespaces, rather it just brings items that the compiler already knows about (such as locally declared modules and/or external dependencies from the `Cargo.toml` file) into the scope of the current file.

Answer (score 4):

Modules in Rust should be declared *explicitly* with [mod declaration](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/modules.html).

Without `mod from_other_file;` which introduces the name `from_other_file` into the current scope Rust knows nothing about it. The name refers to *module item*.

Comment: I know that but why `use` cannot find it by itself. Why Rust doing it like this? I'm new to Rust and currently learning it. Why `use rand::Rng;` can bring it to the scope but `use from_other_file::sub_module;` which is addressing it from the relative path doesn't?

Comment: @ICE You mixed up concepts a bit. Check out this quote from the reference https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/use-declarations.html: _Beginning with the 2018 edition, use declarations can specify an external crate dependency the same way extern crate can._ So the external crate name is always in scope, but `from_other_file` isnt.

Comment: I think Rust developers should change this behavior. `use` should be able to automatically call mod since we are using path referencing rules for it. Rust is a nice language but using `mod` when we have `use` should be considered redundancy.

Comment: @ICE It's not redundant, because `use` and `mod` are doing different things. `mod from_other_file;` is telling Rust to look for a specific module file and add it to the crate; `use` simply allows you to refer to something that you can already access. You can't do `use from_other_file;` by itself because Rust doesn't know what `from_other_file` is.

Comment: I think another way to put this is that `use` is more like `alias` in some languages.  For example in Elixir we can say `alias Foo.Bar` which allows us to refer to `Bar` without its `Foo` qualifier.  To help drive this point home in Rust, we could also write the fully qualified `from_other_file::sub_module::do_something();` inline without `use`ing it.